# Need help with Views and Glossary

Tags: blocks, views

I'm following along on the blog post "Use Views to Create an Alphabetical List of Taxonomy Terms" by Kristin Brinner http://getlevelten.com/blog/kristin-brinner/drupal-tutorial-use-views-create-alphabetical-list-taxonomy-terms and my sample does not produce the results as she shows.

Part 1 & 2: I successfully created a new view selecting taxonomy terms (create as Grid), then grouped terms alphabetically (add Taxonomy term: Name, label it "Grouping", exclude from display, rewrite to max length = 1), then under Grid-Settings use "Grouping"

Part 3, Create a Views page for each letter of the alphabet: I can't see these results, but I presume I did this correctly, using contextual filters,  (Glossary, Character limit 1)

Part 4, Create A-Z list (create a block that will display the list of first letters in a cute list above the grouping grids) isn't working. Here is what the tutorial says should be the result:

[image: Sample from tutorial]

I followed along exactly with the tutorial except When the filter value IS available, the tutorial says Specify validation criteria, Basic Validation, Hide View and I do not have Hide View available.

I don't have an option to Apply, only Save. My content continues to look the same as it did previously in the exercise, i.e. like this (graphic omitted because I don't have enough clearance on this site)

However when I put "S" into the Preview with contextual filters, I get
(graphic omitted because I don't have enough clearance on this site)

So, it looks like it's almost working. Ideas? TIA

Comment: I don't have enough clearance to post my two other screen captures. How do I add them to comments?

Comment: I think you're stuck with combining them into a single image, if you're able.  Label each section as "part X" for as much clarity as you can get.

Comment: Thanks Weston. I have reposted my question per your suggestions. It's here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196045/need-help-with-views-and-glossary-revised

Comment: Notice that you can always edit your questions to change the screenshots you are using. Asking two times the same question will cause one of the questions to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find validation in Contextual Filter. I am attaching screen shot for the same.

[image]

However you can also use the glossary view which is provided by Drupal.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question because you can't see my images, but I have reposted my question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196045/need-help-with-views-and-glossary-revised

Comment: How do you use the glossary view? I couldnt find it when I searched on the /admin/structure/views page